# Documentum: Oracle database Date time difference and I_LATEST_ FLAG

Tags: java, oracle11g, documentum

I am not sure how to phrase technically properly.

### Introductions

We are using documentum 6.0 and oracle 11g. I have try to search documentum using DQL and it fail miserablely in terms of performance even after index and tuning.

Part of the reason is because how documentum translate ->  any (cat="abc" and cat ="aaa" and cat ="ccc") for repeating values

I'm trying to find documents with cat="abc", cat ="aaa" and cat ="ccc", and it will translate into multiple exist in subqueries.

There are also other reasons like joining table and etc.

Therefore I decided to query the generated oracle table directly.

### So far the POC seems rather successful but I have a  few issues

1) I realize the old version are stored in the same table and the newest record is mark by a "1" for I_LATEST_FLAG

May I know where I can find a definition of all the  I_* column created by documentum?

And can I trust that "I_LATEST_FLAG"=1 is always the most current version of a document?

2) I realize the date and time provided by DQL via Documentum adminstrator is accurate but in oracle DB they are a few hours behind.

May I know is there a proper solution to this issue?

3) Anyone using the same solution as me? if so please share other issues that I should look at?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can find definitions of all the dm* objects and their columns in the EMC Documentum System Object Reference. You can download this from EMC's Powerlink site.
2. According to the Object Reference guide, the i_latest_flag this is true when *this version is the most recent version of the object **on a particular branch in the version tree**.*
3. I haven't implemented the solution of querying the DB directly on any systems (and it seems an extreme solution that perhaps indicates a problem with design) so I can't help you with that.

For the time difference between the DQL and the date time stored in the Database, from Documentum 6.0 and above all the dates stored in the DB are stored in UTC and the date sent in the DQL query is considered to be local time of the client making the query, hence the difference. Search Powerlink for how to use the r_tz_aware attribute of the dm_docbase_config and you will find a very helpful technical note by EMC explaining the workings of the Timezone Feature.

Answer (score 1):

For the current version, not to be confused with the last version, the column is 'i_has_folder'.

You can create a view in the DB, register it as a Registered Table in DQL, then query it in DQL. You will get the same date translation this way.

Comment: what is the difference between i_has_folder and i_latest_flag